# mongo db distinct column but include another column value

Tags: mongodb

I'm struggling to find a question just like me but couldn't find one.
So let's say we have a query in mysql:

```
"select distinct user_id, user_name from users"
```

So apart from the distinct values I also extract the names of the distinct users.
How do I do that in mongo? I mean to get a distinct value I have

```
db.collection.distinct(field, query, options)
```

Where field is the name of the distinct column, but how do I add the extra column?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongo's [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) doesn't work the same way SQL distinct works on multiple fields, as you've stated it works perfectly fine on a single field which is the intended usage.

The mongoy way of doing this is using the aggregation pipeline with a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
on multiple fields, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user_id: "$user_id",
        user_name: "$user_name"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_id: "$_id.user_id",
      user_name: "$_id.user_name"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8hI5YZSjRYH)

Comment: I understand, this is like doing distinct user_id, distinct user_name, but what if I wanted to apply the distinct only on user id and then add the column name user_name

Comment: When you say add column what do you mean exactly? in the case 2 users have the same id and different names what would be the expected output? if this is not possible then you don't even need to `$group` you could just fetch all the documents from the db as is.

Comment: oh I get it, i should do db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user_id: "$user_id",
     
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_id: "$_id.user_id",
      user_name: "$user_name"
    }
  }
])

Comment: Yep, you could obviously change the group conditions as you see fit.

Comment: I mean I need to apply the distinct to only one column and the other column value just use without using distinct applied to it, the code I added works now, thank you!!! sorry I don't know how to use proper indentation on comments